# Still getting webdriver.chrome.driver is not set exception, even though I set that property

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I got the following exception when trying to run a Selenium test on Chrome.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
Command duration or timeout: 97 milliseconds
```

I looked it up and both set the webdriver.chrome.driver property with the correct location of the executable. I also put the executable in my path and I still receive the same error. The code snippet is below.

```
//Importing jUnit and Selenium
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class SampleSeleniumTest {
    @Test
    public void sampleTest(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");

        System.out.print(System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver"));
        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
        driver.quit();

    }
}
```

Comment: Which selenium version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, so I instead defined the path in the command line.

java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/path/to/your/chromedriver -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register/

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing chrome driver wrongly.

Instead of this: 
`WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(DesiredCapabilities.chrome());`

Use this : `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`

And use latest version of both **`selenium`** and **`chromeDriver`**

Latest Version of Selenium :**`3.4.0`** & latest version of chrome driver you can download it from here : [Latest Release: ChromeDriver 2.30](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/)